(Portuguese) Diacritics on Capital Letters Messing Up with Line Spacing
Capital letters with diacritics in Portuguese are a little bit taller, but I thought babel would deal with that by default. That doesn't seem to be the case. Is there a workaround?

It's more visible with the font I'm using, which is Adobe Garamond Pro. The 3rd line, with the "É" is a little bit taller:

\documentclass{book}

\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{12pt}{13pt}}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Adobe Garamond Pro}

\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
  Ao longo do livro, os comentários das respostas focam em criar uma ponte entre... a visão de alguém que está começando e aquela de um jogador mais avançado. Mas, mesmo com esses comentários, progredir linearmente neste livro pode ser bem desafiador. Se for este o caso, então melhor ainda, pois é sinal de que há muito o que aprender. É, porém, compreensível a estranheza se a expectativa fosse a de um material de treinamento. Foi um dos focos mas da criação desta coleção, mas, como há muitas técnicas e uma quantidade limitada de papel, o volume de exercícios por tipo de sequência não é tão alto. Mas persevere! Como treinamento, sugiro fortemente refazer o livro múltiplas vezes, provavelmente espaçadas por uma ou mais semanas. Repetição será essencial para tornar as técnicas intuitivas: errar na primeira vez será fácil, errar depois da décima garanto que será muito mais difícil!
\end{document}



Capital letters with diacritics in Portuguese are a little bit taller, but I thought babel would deal with that by default. That doesn't seem to be the case.

Not sure why you think that babel is supposed to do "deal with that".
The setting
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{12pt}{13pt}}

is at the heart of the problem you've encountered. For most Latin-character fonts (other than blackletter, aka "Fraktur", fonts), the default baseline skip is usually between 14pt and 14.5pt if the nominal font size is 12pt. (Aside: 1 "TeX point" equals ca 0.35mm.) Typesetters use the term "leading" for the excess of baseline skip over font size. Hence, the default amount of leading for a 12pt-font is usually between 2pt and 2.5pt; the exact leading amount is an important parameter that's specified by the font's designer(s). Leading serves several purposes. One of them is to permit the insertion of a tall (or deep) glyph without immediately having to increase the distance between lines.
By reducing the leading to just 1pt, you are basically asking for the uneven-baseline problem to occur. The remedy? Don't run renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{12pt}{13pt}} if your document uses a language in which diacritics on top of uppercase letters can and do occur. Instead, just specify 12pt as one of the document class options and use the font's default leading settings.
Two additional comments: (a) One should not run \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} under LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX. (b) There's no point in loading the lmodern ("Latin Modern") package if you're going to subsequently specify a completely different font -- say, Adobe Garamond Pro -- anyway.
The following screenshot places 12pt/13pt text on the left and 12pt/14.5pt text on the right. Note that the text on the right does not exhibit an uneven-baseline problem between lines 2 and 3.

\documentclass[12pt]{book} % compile with either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Adobe Garamond Pro}

\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.495\textwidth}
\fontsize{12pt}{13pt}\selectfont % switch to very narrow leading
Se for este o caso, então melhor ainda, pois é sinal de que há muito o que aprender. 
É, porém, compreensível a estranheza se a expectativa fosse a de um material de treinamento. 
Foi um dos focos mas da criação desta coleção, mas, como há muitas técnicas e uma quantidade limitada de papel,
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.495\textwidth} % use default amount of leading
Se for este o caso, então melhor ainda, pois é sinal de que há muito o que aprender. 
É, porém, compreensível a estranheza se a expectativa fosse a de um material de treinamento. 
Foi um dos focos mas da criação desta coleção, mas, como há muitas técnicas e uma quantidade limitada de papel,
\end{minipage}

\end{document}


Addendum, prompted by @egreg's comment: Another, possibly even more questionable, aspect of executing \renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{12pt}{13pt}} is that this redefinition severely limits what \normalsize is supposed to do. For reference: In the file bk12.clo -- an auxiliary file that's employed if the book document class is used together with the option 12pt -- one finds the following (re)definition of \normalsize:
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xiipt{14.5}%
   \abovedisplayskip 12\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus7\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6.5\p@ \@plus3.5\p@ \@minus3\p@
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
   \let\@listi\@listI}

Here, \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xiipt{14.5} evaluates to \fontsize{12pt}{14.5pt}. Importantly, though, the above definition of \normalsize also resets four length parameters and resets the meaning of \@listi.
The LaTeX kernel, many (all?) document classes (e.g., article, report, book, and many others), and many packages employ \normalsize at various points for various important actions. By limiting \normalsize to merely executing one instruction related to the font size and leading, you're essentially asking for yet more troubling surprises to occur at various points in the document.
In short, don't mess with \normalsize unless you really really know what you're doing. Conversely, if you really really know what you're doing, you will probably already know that it's not necessary to mess with \normalsize in order to achieve whatever it is that you need to accomplish...

Spot on. It may be also an occasion to remark that \normalsize should do much more than setting a font size and leading.

@egreg - Thanks for this suggestion. I've gone ahead and posted an addendum .

Thank you very much for all the corrections, tips and explanations.

“By reducing the leading to just 1pt, you are basically asking for the uneven-baseline problem to occur.” — Why, exactly? Does leading in LaTeX refer to true leading (as in metal typesetting) rather than total line height (as in most digital typesetting contexts and as the value would indicate)? If no, why should the amount matter (a 13pt line height is a 13pt line height regardless of the height of the glyphs on the line)? If yes, why is it specified in a way that makes it look like it refers to baseline distance (e.g., 13pt instead of 1pt)?

@JanusBahsJacquet - Did you read egreg's parallel answer? He showed that for the case of EB Garamond (Adobe Garamond Pro is very similar, by the way), "the distance between consecutive baselines must be at least 13.476pt, plus some padding in order to avoid clashing characters. Half a point is really a bare minimum [for the extra padding]." In other words, he found that ca 14pt -- which works out to 2pt of leading -- is required. But the OP is specifying only 1pt as the amount of leading. [to be continued]

@JanusBahsJacquet - [continued] Thus, whenever an uppercase glyph with a diacritic is encountered, TeX is forced to increase the leading "on the fly" in order to prevent a clash of glyphs -- and create an uneven linespacing issue. Importantly, this emergency increase wouldn't be necessary at all if the OP hadn't specified just 1pt of leading. That's why I wrote that specifying an insufficient amount of leading is "basically asking for the uneven-baseline problem to occur." I'm no expert in typographic terminology, but I'm confident that I used the term "leading" consistently in my answer.

I did read the other answer, but as I understand it, that just gives the minimum line height to avoid clashing characters. Other typesetting software would simply let characters clash if the leading is smaller than the text height, but you’re saying, then, that LaTeX does not allow this but treats leading as inherently additive to the height of the characters and forces increased leading to avoid clashes? So something like 12pt/10pt just can’t be done (with this technique, at least)?

@JanusBahsJacquet - I absolutely did not write, nor did I imply, that "LaTeX treats leading as inherently additive to the height of the characters". I also have no idea what "other typesetting software" you may have in mind; I only know stuff about TeX and LaTeX. You've learned from egreg's answer that "the minimum line height to avoid clashing characters" is ca. 14pt for the font at hand. But because the OP has set the line height to just 13pt, clashing characters will occur if a line contains a tall glyph such as É -- forcing TeX to increase the line-height on an emergency basis.

@JanusBahsJacquet - I have definitely never seen 12pt/10pt -- with negative leading of 2pt?? -- done in a LaTeX document. Just out of curiosity: What would be the point of causing frequent and massive character clashes across lines?

By ‘other typesetting software’, I mean things like Word, InDesign, Pages, even online typography – they all allow negative leading. It’s sometimes useful in titles or headers with large font sizes, but of course not advisable for running text. If LaTeX does not allow the baseline skip to be less than the height of the tallest character on the line, that is exactly what I meant by treating leading as inherently additive (as opposed to potentially subtractive). That’s also how true/physical leading (= lead blocks inserted between lines in metal typesetting) works.

To give a more detailed comparison with other software: In Word, for example, you can set the line height to be relative (e.g., 1 or 1.2), and this uses the height of the tallest character on the line as its basis; so text set in 12pt/1 will give a similar end result to the 12pt/13pt example here, with uneven line heights. Conversely, if you set the line height to a fixed number (e.g., 13pt), then that will always be the line height, regardless of the point size of the text or the height of any characters on the line. I suspect the latter is how psygo expected 12pt/13pt to work here, too.

@JanusBahsJacquet - Thanks for clarifying your main points. I guess there was, at the onset, some uncertainty over what the term "leading" could mean in a TeX/LaTeX context. I hope I was able to address your major questions.

In addition to Mico's very fine answer, I'd like to add some more details.
Your code
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{12pt}{13pt}}

seems to hint that you want

normal fontsize 12pt
footnote size 10pt

but, apart from the considerations about \normalsize doing much more than setting size and leading, the code fails to do what you believe, because \normalsize is exactly what you redefine in the second line. Thus footnotes will appear at 12pt size. Try it.
Some more words on interline space. Let me use the 12pt option and see how much we can safely reduce the leading.
I'll use EB Garamond as I don't have Adobe Garamond Pro.
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond}

\begin{document}

\sbox0{y} \the\dp0

\sbox0{ÁÉÓÂÊÔÃẼÕ} \the\ht0

\end{document}

The output will be

3.42pt
10.056pt

This means that the distance between consecutive baselines must be at least 13.476pt, plus some padding in order to avoid clashing characters. Half a point is really a bare minimum.
If we add \the\baselineskip, we see 14.5pt. You might try to reduce to 14pt. Here's how: set \linespread to an approximation of 14/14.5.
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond}

\linespread{0.966} % to get 14pt baseline skip

\begin{document}

\the\baselineskip

Ao longo do livro, os comentários das respostas focam em criar 
uma ponte entre... a visão de alguém que está começando e aquela 
de um jogador mais avançado. Mas, mesmo com esses comentários, 
progredir linearmente neste livro pode ser bem desafiador. 
Se for este o caso, então melhor ainda, pois é sinal de que 
há muito o que aprender. É, porém, compreensível a estranheza 
se a expectativa fosse a de um material de treinamento. Foi um 
dos focos mas da criação desta coleção, mas, como há muitas 
técnicas e uma quantidade limitada de papel, o volume de 
exercícios por tipo de sequência não é tão alto. Mas persevere! 
Como treinamento, sugiro fortemente refazer o livro múltiplas 
vezes, provavelmente espaçadas por uma ou mais semanas. 
Repetição será essencial para tornar as técnicas intuitivas: 
errar na primeira vez será fácil, errar depois da décima garanto 
que será muito mais difícil!

\bigskip

\linespread{1}\selectfont % to see the same with standard baseline skip

\the\baselineskip

Ao longo do livro, os comentários das respostas focam em criar 
uma ponte entre... a visão de alguém que está começando e aquela 
de um jogador mais avançado. Mas, mesmo com esses comentários, 
progredir linearmente neste livro pode ser bem desafiador. 
Se for este o caso, então melhor ainda, pois é sinal de que 
há muito o que aprender. É, porém, compreensível a estranheza 
se a expectativa fosse a de um material de treinamento. Foi um 
dos focos mas da criação desta coleção, mas, como há muitas 
técnicas e uma quantidade limitada de papel, o volume de 
exercícios por tipo de sequência não é tão alto. Mas persevere! 
Como treinamento, sugiro fortemente refazer o livro múltiplas 
vezes, provavelmente espaçadas por uma ou mais semanas. 
Repetição será essencial para tornar as técnicas intuitivas: 
errar na primeira vez será fácil, errar depois da décima garanto 
que será muito mais difícil!

\end{document}


You should test with your actual font.

+1 for the additional, in-depth (pun intended...) explanations. :-)
